# How Can I Show html entities contained <script>alert();</script> with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have json array Which contains value like

```
[0=>'<script>alert();</script>',1=>'test',...etc]
```

This array is generating from Mysql DB content.

I want to show the same text (`<script type="text/javascript">alert();</script>`) without executing JS with a select option each function.

Please help me.

Comment: can you show us, what you have tried for it?

Comment: JS wont be executed until and unless you put it inside <script></script> tags. You can just put it in the options for select. Also you can use htmlentities($str) just to be sure

Comment: var option_mat = '<option value="">Select Primary</option>';
            $(json['material_array']).each(function (key, v) { 
                option_mat += '<option  value="' + v.id + '">' + v.name + ' - ' + v.long_name + '</option>';
            }); 
This the sample code. @vikscool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(JSON.parse(response_json), function (index, value) {
                var short_txt = $("<div></div>").text(value.value_name).html();
                var long_txt = $("<div></div>").text(value.long_text).html();
                $html += '<li onclick="selectSuggestion_template(\'' + escape(value.value_name) + '\',' + val_id + ',\'' + escape(value.long_text) + '\');">' + short_txt + ' - ' + long_txt + '</li>';
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Found the solution Like This:

```js
var jsonData = { 
  "data":[{"id":"67","name":"\"kakkkke\"","long_name":"\"kakkkke\""},
{"id":"71","name":"<script type=\"text\/javascript\">alert();<\/script>",
"long_name":"<script type=\"text\/javascript\">alert();<\/script>"},
{"id":"1","name":"00ABRA","long_name":"ABRASIVES"}]
};
var options = '<option value="">---</option>';
var dataArrayValue = [];
$.each( jsonData.data, function(i, data) {
  options += '<option value="' + data.id + '">' + '</option>';
  dataArrayValue[data.id] = data.name + ' - ' + data.long_name;
});
$('#adddata').html(options);
$('#adddata option').each(function (key, v) {
  var attrval = parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
  $(this).text(dataArrayValue[attrval]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="adddata" id="adddata">
</select>
```